# Unable to understand dtype errors in opencv2 python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


########################
# function#
########################

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, params):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 100, (0, 0, 255), -1)
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 100, (0, 255, 0), -1)
    else:
        return


cv2.namedWindow(winname="output")
cv2.setMouseCallback("output", draw_circle)


##########################
######showing images#####
##########################

img = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), dtype=np.int8) #----------- problem here

while True:
    cv2.imshow("output", img)

    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am new to opencv2 python... the above is my code, i am unable to figure out the issue.....
when **dtype** was **np.int8** i was able to draw circle but,  when i changed it to **np.int16** i was unable to draw the circles

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to draw into 16bit image, then you need to use 16bit color.

As Dan noted, `imshow` will scale the 16bit value into 8bit for display. `(0,255,0)` becomes `(0,0,0)` that's why you get only black image.
Use `(0,255*256,0)` instead.

Comment: From [documentation of `imshow`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563): "If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255]."